# Python how to remove decimal?

Tags: python, integer, decimal

I've found some other topics on this but I couldn't get it to work. Please pardon my naivety with Python.

```
Berekening1 = 8.5
Berekening2 = 8.1+4.8
Berekening3 = 8*10
Berekening4 = 3
x = Berekening1 * Berekening2 * Berekening3 + Berekening4
print "Het antwoord van de berekening is:",
round(x); print x,
print "."
```

I want `x` to be an integer. How do I do that? I tried both `int` and `round`.

Anyone also have an idea on how to remove the "space" between `x` and "." at the end when code is executed?

Comment: `x = int(x)` may be or `x=round(x)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since the common language on SO is English, it is best to translate your variable names and printable text to English as well. This results in more people than just the Dutch and Flemish being able to understand your code.

Comment: I got it working now like this

print int(x),

Answer (score 8):

You would need to reassign x to the value of `x = int(x)` or  you could also use str.format if you just want the output formatted:

```
print "Het antwoord van de berekening is: {:.0f}.".format(x)
```

int and round will exhibit different behaviour, if you have anything >= 5 after the decimal point then `int` will floor but round will round up, if you want to actually use round you might want to combine the two:

```
In [7]: x = round(1.5)

In [8]: x
Out[8]: 2.0

In [9]: int(x)
Out[9]: 2
```

Or again combine with `str.format`:

```
In [10]: print "Het antwoord van de berekening is: {:.0f}".format(round(1.5))
Het antwoord van de berekening is: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The `round()` function cannot alter the `x` variable in place, as numbers are immutable. Instead, the rounded result is returned, which your code ignores.

Store the result back in `x`:

```
x = round(x)
```

This will give you a floating point number rounded to the nearest whole number.

Alternatively, use `x = int(x)`, which gives you an integer number, but *floors* that number (removes the decimal portion regardless if it is closer to the next whole number or not).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes, I state that in my answer.

Comment: Yep, sorry missed that

Comment: round will when x is say 8.5, round to 8. 8 and 9 are both nearest whole numbers in this case. So round has a prejudice to floor, rather than to ceiling, when decimal part is exactly .5

Answer (score 1):

For just removing decimal part of an integer(eg- 45.55 to 45), you can try using `trunc()` method with math library, just like this-

```
import math
i=45.55
i=math.trunc(i)
print(i)
```

Output will be- 45, trunc() method doesn't rounds off the integer to the nearest whole number, it justs cuts off the decimal portion.

Or if you want to round off then you can use the `round()` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions in Python, they are providing two different results:

```
some_float = 10.7
print(int(some_float)) 
print(round(some_float)) 

[output]10
[output]11
```

Then, if you want "." but have don't want to have zeroes after the number you may easily print out in the following way:

```
print(str(round(some_float))+".")
[output]11.
```